# codeigniter, file not found error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some new site maked by codeigniter. The site turns right on localhost (Windows 7 and easyPHP dev-server) but when I move the hole files to the live server I got a "file not found" error.

I have the following route.php :

```
    ...
    $route['login'] = 'User/login';
    ...
    $route['default_controller'] = 'User/Login';
    $route['404_override'] = '';
    $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

The problem is when I call the default route `www.mydomaine.com` I got the login page right, but when i add the login route `www.mydomaine.com/login` I got a "file not found" error despite I call the same controller/function I both routes.

someone can help me please.

Comment: check htaccess file and ensure that rewrite base rule is right, please share it here

Answer (score 0):

check your .htaccess file first.try like this:

```
$route['login'] = 'index.php/User/login';
```

if it work ! your problem is in you htaccess file.

```
$route['login'] = 'User/login';
```

this mean you must have controller User and function name Login.check it out.
hope it's help.